# Ref proof for equidistribution of roots of $x^2 \equiv 1$ (mod $p$), as $p$ varies over primes?

Tags: number-theory, equidistribution

This question is about equidistribution of roots of quadratic congruences of the form $x^2 \equiv n$ (mod $p$), which we note always have determinant $D = b^2 - 4ac = 4n$. This is for a fixed $n$ while $p$ varies over primes.

The equidistribution papers typically referenced in this area have significant constraints:

- [DFI 1995] proves equidistribution for all quadratic congruences with negative discriminant D.
- [Toth 2000] extends the proof to quadratics with positive discriminants, but D must not be a square.
- [DFI 2012] extends the proof to quadratics with positive fundamental discriminants, then sketches how to address negative fundamental discriminants. They say, “Extensions to non-fundamental discriminants are also possible”, but they do not say how to do so. This means the positive values of n are restricted to {2,3,6,7,10,11,etc}, to produce a fundamental discriminant.

So we see that n=1, D=4 has a positive discriminant that is both non-fundamental and is a square.  Thus the above papers do not seem to prove equidistribution for the roots of $x^2 \equiv 1$ (mod $p$).

Yet, respected authors including [FI 2010] and [SSZ 2020] claim that we have established equidistribution for ALL simple quadratic congruences $x^2 \equiv n$ (mod $p$) over primes, without exceptions. If so, there must be a proof of equidistribution for non-fundamental and/or square positive determinants. I have not been able to search out such a proof.

Can someone please provide a reference to an authoritative proof for this, hopefully with best bounds for the discrepancy?

——— 
References 
[DFI 1995] Duke, W., J. B. Friedlander, and H. Iwaniec. “Equidistribution of roots of a quadratic congruence to prime moduli.” Annals of Mathematics 141 (1995): 423–41.
[Toth 2000] A. T ́oth, ‘Roots of quadratic congruences’, Int. Math. Res. Not., 14 (2000), 719–739. 
[DFI 2012]  W. Duke, J. Friedlander and H. Iwaniec, ‘Weyl sums for quadratic roots’, Int. Math. Res. Not. (2012), 2493 - 2549. 
[FI 2010] Friedlander, J. B. and H. Iwaniec. Opera de Cribro. Colloquium Publications 57. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society, 2010; ref. Theorem 19.2
[SSZ 2020] Shkredov, I.D., Shparlinski, I.E., & Zaharescu, A. (2020). On the distribution of modular square roots of primes. arXiv: Number Theory.

Comment: $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ is trival: its solutions are $1, p-1$. In particular they not seem to be equidistributed at all

Comment: Hi @Crostul, thanks for reading.  I’m still learning about equidistribution (e.d.) so this will be a very basic response. While your comment is correct for any given p, the e.d. in question is for the sequence of normalized values $\{v/p\}$, ordered by increasing $p$, where $v$ are roots mod $p$, $v < p$, $p$ varies over all primes $< P$, as $P \to \infty$. That such sequences are e.d. for at least some quadratic congruences is not my claim, but proven by the widely accepted papers mentioned.

Comment: That said, I too do not see how $n$ being a perfect square can result in e.d., because such a distribution must be “dense” throughout the interval $[0,1)$, and if $n$ is square I only see the distribution being dense toward the endpoints of that interval and not in the middle. Whereas I can see it working with non-square or negative square $n$.  That’s why I’m looking for the proof!  :-)  But perhaps the latter two cites just assumed the constraints were well-known.